# Grout or caulk on tile floor to tile wall

Tags: bathroom, tile, grout, caulking

My shower has tile floors and walls and the connection between them is very rough and needs to be re-done.  It looks like previously there was some caulk added in spots.

What is the recommended product for this location?  Grout or Caulk?  I've read that caulk tends to mold over time.  If it is grout, how do you grout in a 90 degree angle like this?

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Caulk is the way to go when there is a change of plane as there are shifts in the structure that will crack regular grout. You should clean all that mess out of there with a utility knife, single edge razor blades, a #10 scalpel, whatever. Clean out with some vinegar to kill any mold residue, let dry and re caulk with  quality silicone caulk.

The only time grout would/could be used here is if you use the epoxy grout. It is more expensive and harder to work with but will yield great results.

By the way, all wet surfaces will mold over time without regular cleaning.

You would grout a location like this by placing mixed grout on the floor and ramming it into the crack with a grout float... something like a thick rubber trowel....

Comment: Would the epoxy grout also crack because of shifting or would that hold up better? If it doesn't crack would you still do caulk over the epoxy?

Comment: Epoxy grout will not crack and will hold up much better under those conditions and you do not caulk over it because it it totally water proof.